# How to call vacuum with a dry run in Python for a Delta Lake

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I can see an example on how to call the vacuum function for a Delta lake in python [here](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-utility.html). But how do I call it for only a dry run? In other words, what is the equivalent Python code for the following?

```
%sql
VACUUM delta.`dbfs:/mnt/<myfolder>` DRY RUN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dry run for non-SQL code is not yet available in Delta version 0.8.

There is an issue [Vacuum dry run unavailable - deleted file information unexposed #454](https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/454) open on GitHub.